# Controlling the heartbeat timeout from the client in socket.io

Tags: node.js, client, socket.io

I have mobile clients connected to a node.js server, running socket.io via xhr-polling. I have two type of clients:

- Type A

  When the connection breaks up due to network problems (or that the
  client crashes) the default heart beat timeout is too long
- Type B

  When the connection breaks up for this client I need to give it more
  time to recover - it is more important that the client recovers than
  the server breaks the connection/session

So my question is how to I configure (if it is possible) the heartbeat timeouts from the actual client?

Comment: Not sure about heartbeat timeout, but if you are using socket.io-client there are some useful options that might help you, like `connect timeout` `reconnection delay` `max reconnection attempts`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there are 2 values that matter here: the server sends heartbeats to the client every `heartbeat interval` seconds; the client responds directly, if there is no response, the server decides the client is dead. The client waits for a heartbeat from the server for `heartbeat timeout` seconds since the last heartbeat (which should obviously be higher than the `heartbeat interval`). If it hasn't received word from the server in `heartbeat timeout` seconds, it assumes the server is dead (and will start disconnecting / reconnecting based on the other options you have set.

Default values are `heartbeat interval = 25s` and `heartbeat timeout = 60s`. Both items are set on the server, the `heartbeat timeout` is sent to the client upon connecting.

Changing the `heartbeat timeout` for a single client is easy:

```
var socket = io.connect(url);
socket.heartbeatTimeout = 20000; // reconnect if not received heartbeat for 20 seconds
```

However on the server, the `heartbeat interval` value seems to be part of a shared object (the Manager, which is what you get back from your `var io = require("socket.io").listen(server)` call), which means that it can't easily be changed for individual sockets.

I'm sure that with some socket.io hacking you should be able to make it happen, but you might break other stuff in the process...

Comment: rather see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31146441/671457 @Joseph238's answer if you''re from the future like me.

Answer (score 27):

In socket.io 1.x, the API has changed but the concept remains the same.

Instead of heartbeatInterval and heartbeatTimeout, the properties are pingInterval and pingTimeout. For example,

```
var server = app.listen(80);
io = socketio(server,{'pingInterval': 45000});
```

See the documentation at http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#server(opts:object), which will direct you to https://github.com/Automattic/engine.io#methods-1.

Answer (score 11):

To complete Claude's answer, you can set these values at the server lever, with the following code

```
io.set('heartbeat interval', 5);
io.set('heartbeat timeout', 11);
```

and then you could create 2 node.js servers, one for each type of client (A and B), having 2 desired set of options (heartbeat timeout and interval).

Comment: can it be found in any documentation somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found this in any documentation, which is rather short anyway. But in practice I have noticed using the above code, the values actually get changed.

Comment: This answer is valid for socket.io 0.9.*. Documentation in socket.io/lib/master.js.