# socket.io client disconnecting when sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have an application where the client is supposed to send an object to the server around every minute.

Most of the time, the message won't arrive to the server. However, the server recieves the disconnect event from the client.

In the client browser, these messages are showed when it is supposed to send the object.

```
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438601847651-2".16.Request.create @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:2Request @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.XHR.request @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.XHR.doPoll @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:217.Polling.poll @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:217.Polling.doOpen @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:213.Transport.open @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:112.Socket.open @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1Socket @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1Socket @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:13.Manager.open.Manager.connect @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1(anonymous function) @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1
socket.io-1.2.0.js:2 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438601847675-3&sid=6j2loOyIEXlIzwlwAAAC".16.Request.create @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:2Request @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.XHR.request @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.XHR.doPoll @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:217.Polling.poll @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:217.Polling.onData @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:2(anonymous function) @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:28.Emitter.emit @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:116.Request.onData @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.Request.onLoad @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.Request.create.xhr.onreadystatechange @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:2
socket.io-1.2.0.js:2 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438602315276-4".16.Request.create @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:2Request @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.XHR.request @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:216.XHR.doPoll @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:217.Polling.poll @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:217.Polling.doOpen @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:213.Transport.open @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:112.Socket.open @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1Socket @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1Socket @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:13.Manager.open.Manager.connect @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1(anonymous function) @ socket.io-1.2.0.js:1
socket.io-1.2.0.js:2 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1438602315303-5&sid=z7RLpEScG6Lj_cIgAAAE".
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this post:

[Controlling the heartbeat timeout from the client in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815231/controlling-the-heartbeat-timeout-from-the-client-in-socket-io)

your sockets connection timeout is probably exceeded due to a a too short timeout period. Try increasing it like in the thread  in the above URL.

Hope this helped.