# Custom ping-pong socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When you open chrome dev tools, in "frames" tab of our websocket you will notice periodic data sending-receiving (called "ping" for client request and "pong" for server responses).
Well, in socket.io v.1.4.5 you would just see these:

```
2
3
2
3
2
3
```

And so on. Can I attach some data to these periodic transactions? I would like to make kinda this:

```
2['ping',{data:data}]
3['pong',{data:data}]
```

I've already found that:

1. For some reasons clients can't make `socket.emit('ping',{})` by
   itself
2. Server can't detect event like
   `socket.on('ping',function)`

The point is to make those ping-pong more meaningful and to kill two birds with one stone

Answer (score 2):

Just to add up on the answer posted by, [oleksii-shnyra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5843293/oleksii-shnyra).

As per [Socket.IO Docs](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md), there are some reserved events and shouldn't be used.

If you are using [socket.io-client](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client), you can listen for 'Ping' & 'Pong' events in the client side. You would see the latency for 'Pong' event. For example the below code,

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('Some_IP_Address:PORT');

socket.on('connect', function() {
  console.log("Client is Connected");
});

socket.on('pong', function(data) {
  console.log('Received Pong: ', data);
});
```

I received the below output in the console.

```
Client is Connected
Received Pong:  143
Received Pong:  143
Received Pong:  148
Received Pong:  147
```

As per documentation, '143' is the latency in 'ms' since the 'ping' was sent from client.

*Note:* You can listen for 'Ping' event as well but it usually returns empty data.

However you wouldn't be able to listen to the Ping/Pong events on the server side.

Comment: Is there any way to configure the time interval which the ping events are sent from client?

Answer (score 1):

I am not intimately familiar with under-the-hood workings of socketeio or websockets however I really doubt that you can extend those polling events that socketio sends. On top of that, I do think that tinkering with those would not be healthy for your socketio solution, better leave it as it is and implement your custom events as needed.

P.S. socketio does not prevent you from using 'ping' and 'pong' as your custom event names. Double check your code :)

Comment: In socket.io.js for client you can find string that says: `Internal events (blacklisted). These events can't be emitted by the user.`And one of those - "ping" event.

Comment: maybe you are not using the same version because I did emit those ping/pong events before writing my answer and I am using socketio version 1.3.5

Comment: Yeah, I'm using 1.4.5

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a way to set an interval to determine disconnection from the server or internet and this page helped me
[Click me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31146441/14274230)

[Github docs](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1)

I used it in the backend

```
{
   pingTimeout: 2000,
   pingInterval: 3000,
}
```

I hope this will save someone time.