# WebSocket seemingly closed by Google Chrome for no reason

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm using Socket.io to create a WebSocket connection with Node.js. At some point, I have a long running function that blocks the main thread, after this happens, the transport (in this case websockets) is closed seemingly by Google Chrome itself.

There is no disconnect message at all on the backend and the message in the `close` event is simply `transport close`.

Does anyone have any idea how/why this happens? I've played around with the timeout of Socket.io (`pingTimeout` and `pingInterval`) but that doesn't seem to have any effect on my situation.

EDIT: OK I've tried to change the `pingTimeout` and `pingInterval` both on the server and the client, to no avail..

Here is the code I used:

**Client:**

```
this._socket = io(location.href, {
    path: `${location.path}socket.io`,
    reconnection: false,
    pingTimeout: 120000,
    pingInterval: 60000
});
```

**Server:**

```
const server = http.createServer();
const io = socketio(server, {
    pingTimeout: 120000,
    pingInterval: 60000
});
```

Comment: The place to start is: "long running function that blocks the main thead".  Not a good idea.  If this is socket.io, then it's probably because you aren't allowing the client to handle ping/pong messages that socket.io uses to see if the socket is still alive.  Also, please show us your specific code and exactly what you tried with timeouts.  "played around with the timeout" does not tell us at all what you tried or what things you set.  Questions about code should contain your actual code!  We do very poorly here with theoretical or hypothetical questions and do very well with real code.

Comment: Socket.io has a timeout for the heartbeat (ping/pong) which is 60s by default. I know that the long running function is not a good idea, but until this is solved I need to know exactly what's causing the disconnect. Is it possible that Google Chrome disconnect because it does not have this timeout for heartbeats?

Adding code for this here is very difficult since it's literally just: connect to server, block main thread, gone connection. Currently I use this code to simulate a blocking function: `let a = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
            a += i;
        }`

Comment: When you say you "played around with the timeout", I want to see EXACTLY what code you tried.  There are a number of settings, the doc isn't very good.  I  want to know what you actually tried.  Show us the code.  And, how long a long running function are you trying to handle?  Tells us how many seconds.  And, do you control the serve configuration too?  There's simply not enough info in your current question for us to do anything but guess and questions where we gave to guess, by definition, are not very complete questions.

Comment: I've added the timeout properties you asked, the code for the long running function is in my comment. This blocks the UI thread for about 3-5 seconds. I control both endpoints.

Comment: I asked you to show me the CODE you used to set those timing intervals.  I want to first see if you're even doing it correctly.

Comment: Relevant code to reproduce the error should be pasted into your question, not linked to in a separate repo.

Comment: There is no way to able to fully capture the situation with just some copy-pasting of code.

Comment: Well, this is taken right from [stack overflow's help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) about on-topic questions: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. ... See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)*

Comment: I understand that, but how is that possible if the code involves a two piece application that require communication with each other?

Comment: To create a good question here, it is your responsibility to provide ***the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself***.  Just because your have two pieces of code communicating with one another does not make that any less feasible or desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Per the description in [this answer - Controlling the heartbeat from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815231/controlling-the-heartbeat-timeout-from-the-client-in-socket-io), you have two issues to be conncered about:

1) Server sends heartbeat to the client and then waits some timeout period for a response.  If not response is sent back, then the server assumes the socket is not functioning and closes it.

2) Client waits for a heartbeat from the server for some interval and if it does receive the heartbeat, then it assumes the socket is not functioning and close it and attempts to reconnect.

So, to lengthen the period of time that your socket can last without activity, you have to change the timing on both client and server ends of the connection.  Changing it only on the client will not keep the server from closing a connection that it has failed to get a response to its heartbeat message.  More discussion of how to change those heartbeat intervals and timeouts here: [Controlling the heartbeat timeout from the client in socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815231/controlling-the-heartbeat-timeout-from-the-client-in-socket-io)

When reading about this topic be very careful that what you are reading applies to socket.io 1.x and not older versions because lots of things changed with 1.x.

Comment: I did in fact try to do this on the server alone. Thanks for your input, I will read the posts you linked and see if they help me out.

Comment: @robin_f - you need to configure longer timeout on both client and server.

Comment: I tried this, it still closes with error code 1005 and no message after the loop is done. Even with a stupidly long timeout and interval. I updated the original question.

Comment: @Robin_f - What code gives you the error 1005 and what loop?   Please show code for those.

Comment: I'm pretty sure all of the code is there.. but since it's not clear enough, I'll make a repo with an example when I have some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm having the same issue:
[Way to prevent socket.io from disconnecting on the client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523279/way-to-prevent-socket-io-from-disconnecting-on-the-client-side?noredirect=1#comment78023020_45523279)

The crazy thing is I have pingTimout set to a ridiculously high number, so there must be something else that is closing the connection. But it does seem correlated with the main thread being clogged up.